# Display Some text in some specific category not all category

Tags: categories, single

I want to display some texts in specific category in single post based on category in wordpress.. how can i do that

for example posts in news category display some text.(not all category)

Thank you

Comment: The same text for all posts? Where do you want the text to appear?

Comment: yes in particular category only same text

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in single.php where you need to show it:

```
<?php 
$catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
foreach ($catarray as $cat) {
    $catid = $cat->term_id;

    if ($catid == 5) {
      echo 'TEXT HERE';
    }
    if ($catid == 7) {
      echo 'ANOTHER TEXT';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.. but i added it displays nothing   i have added this code in single.php   <?php 
 $catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
 $catid = $catarray[0]->term_id;
 //show text if category id is 5
 if ($catid == 171) {
   echo 'kannada mp3 kannada songs';
 }
 //another
 if ($catid == 48) {
   echo 'Kannada news';
 }
?>

Comment: where you put it? can upload scr?

Comment: Do you have just a single category per post? Otherwise, you'll have to check all of them in the array `$catarray`.

Comment: no  i have multiple category for single post..added in single.php   screenshot https://imgur.com/a/bKez2   results post  http://www.newkannada.com/dheera-kannada-songs-download.html

Comment: try updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To show specific text in a single post based on the category in WP set condition for allows content display.

Replace `your_category_slug` with the slug of the category you want to target. You can use `has_category()` function to check if the post belongs to a specific category.

```
if(has_category('your_category_slug')){
    // Content to display if the post is in the specified category
    echo '<p>TEXT HERE</p>';
} else {
    // Default content to display if the post is not in the specified category
    the_content();
}
```